# How to draw a circular edge rectangle drawable in android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-drawable, rounded-corners

I tried to draw a drawable like this in xml file:

[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<item android:bottom="50dp">
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
        <solid android:color="#fb1832" />
        <size
            android:width="300dp"
            android:height="150dp" />
    </shape>
</item>

<item
    android:left="100dp"
    android:right="100dp"
    android:top="100dp">
    <shape android:shape="oval">
        <solid android:color="#fb1832" />
    </shape>
</item>
```

But the result is this:

[image]

How to round the corners between that circle and that rectangle?

**Note**: I want to use the `elevation` for this drawable later.

Answer (score 1):

You can create this shape in any tool like lunacy,photoshop,illustrator and then export it as svg and then import it in the android studio.